# Font Icon as squares in Android 2.3.3 browser

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-face

(I'm asking this and answering myself just in case it could help somebody else):

Couldn't make use of jquery.raty.js (http://wbotelhos.com/raty) plugin on android 2.3.3 browser because the stars renders as blank squares (when using the render as font icon option).

The CSS is declared like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "raty";
  src: url("../fonts/raty.eot") format ("eot");
  src: url("../fonts/raty.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype");
  src: url("../fonts/raty.svg#raty") format("svg");
  src: url("../fonts/raty.ttf") format("truetype");
  src: url("../fonts/raty.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I rearranged the order of the src declaration, it seem to work in some browsers and not in others...

Worked when I declared the css like this:

```
@charset "UTF-8";   /*  <-- note: first row, first column */
@font-face {
  font-family: "raty";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/raty.eot"),
       url("../fonts/raty.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("../fonts/raty.woff") format("woff"),
       url("../fonts/raty.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("../fonts/raty.svg#raty") format("svg");
}
```

Please note that instead of several src declarations, I have only one with comma separated urls...

Don't know exactly what it does, but it works consistently through all browsers now.
(Took the idea from icomoon.io exported css)

have a nice day
/j